# Find the intersection from the interior of the circle

Tags: geometry, circles

Given a distance from the origin $d$ along the $y$ axis and the radius $r$ of the circle, how could you find intersection of a ray cast from $d$ and the circle in any unit vector direction.

Going straight up is trivial, it's just the top of the circle, going immediately to the left or right is pretty simple as well, using $r*\sin\arccos(d/r)$ or $r*\sqrt{1-(d/r)^2}$

Trying to generalize it for any direction is a bit tricky. Here's a horrible paint picture to illustrate the problem:
[image: if you can't see this, it probably wouldn't have helped anyway]

Secondly, here's a much nicer desmos graph I set up that illustrates the problem. I made a very naive "Result" variable which is not correct. In that graph, for any direction the result should be the intersection of the black ray and the red circle.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e0ojqjxspx

How would I go about doing this? I imagine I can just use the tried and true line-circle intersection, but I would love to simplify it considering how static my problem space is.

Comment: With both the $y$-intercept and direction of the ray variable, it is clear that this is merely the general circle/line intersection cloaked in several variables. So you have little simplifications to go by.

Comment: Hint: use the polar equation of an off-center circle.

Answer (score 1):

The intersection point has coordinates:

$$\binom{X}{Y}=\binom{0}{d}+\rho\binom{ \cos \theta}{\sin \theta}=\binom{0+\rho \cos \theta}{d+\rho \sin \theta}$$

with known $d$ and $\theta$ and unknown $\rho$.

It must belong to the circle with equation $X^2+Y^2=r^2$ (with $r$ known as well). Thus, you have to solve the following equation for $\rho$:

$$(\rho \cos \theta)^2+(d+\rho \sin \theta)^2=r^2$$

$$\rho^2+(2 d \sin \theta)\rho+(d^2-r^2)=0$$

I let you solve this quadratic equation in variable $\rho$.

The fact that there are two roots $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ shouldn't come as a surprise ; you will have to select among them the one that gives the highest value for $Y$.